# Add userdata for aws instance using data-source in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I need to create an AWS instance with user-data using terraform. I'm using `terraform 0.10.0`.

**ec2.tf**

```
data "template_file" "user_data" {
  template = "userdata.tpl"
}

resource "aws_instance" "fluentd-web" {
  ami           = "${lookup(var.amis, var.aws_region)}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  subnet_id = "${var.subnet_id}"
  user_data = "${data.template_file.user_data.rendered}"
  security_groups =[ "${aws_security_group.ec2_sg.id}" ]
  connection {
     ***
  }
}
```

**userdata.tpl**

```
#! /bin/bash

apt install <**>
```

On applying the terraform, It shows no error. But the contents of the file is not getting populated as user-data. It just shows the file name as user-data.
[image: AWS Console]

How can I get the contents of the file as user-data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the template as below:

```
template = "${file("${path.module}/userdata.tpl")}"
```

Here we use `${path.module}` to get a module-relative path.

Reference: https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/create.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `template` value has to sourced the userdata file as follow:

```
 template = "${file("userdata.tpl")}"
```